# Make dashed line in Unity 2D like in Blender

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to draw dashed line in Unity with in 2D game like in Blender when you hit B for box select mode.

[image]

I tried out lot of tutorials on internet, but nothing seems to work for me.
I'm using Unity 2019.3.0f3 and C#.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create a new material with dashed texture and use Transparent diffuse shader and then use it as line renderer material

Comment: I've tried that, but Unity just always cut out transparent parts of image, so it just shown black part of image, and that looked like normal line.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try transparent diffuse shader for your material